# How to remove the hard brackets from a variable in a windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I am a windows batch dunce.

I have a variable storing some text surrounded by hard brackets like:

```
[glcikLhvxq1BwPBZN0EGMQ==]
```

But I need to pass it as an argument like:

```
glcikLhvxq1BwPBZN0EGMQ==
```

How can I strip these hard brackets from the beginning and end in my windows batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sub-string syntax:

```
set foo=[glcikLhvxq1BwPBZN0EGMQ==]
set foo2=%foo:~1,-1%
```

which will remove the first and last characters. The sub-string starts here at the *second* character (so 1, zero-based) and extends until the second-to-last character (`-1`).

This is detailed more thoroughly in `help set`.

Comment: Excellent! I'm going to give it a try going directly into the argument, but very helpful none the less!